# MySQL -- Adding candidate keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with multiple tables, and for two of the tables, I have a candidate key along with the primary key. I know there's no syntax for candidate keys, so how would I represent this?

Here's the code. I would like SSN to be a candidate key for Patient, as well as for Employee. What should I do? Thanks.

```
create table Employee(
ID int(8),
Fname varchar(20),
Lname varchar(20),
SSN char(11),
Specialty varchar(15),
dateofHire date,
primary key(ID)

);

create table Patient(
num int(8),
Fname varchar(20),
Lname varchar(20),
SSN char(11),
dateofBirth date,   
primary key(num)

);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Candidate keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) are *not* directly manifested in SQL-relational databases as a separate type - they are "left" in the RA conceptual zone.

However, a [*Unique Index / Constraint*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) (over one or more columns) can be used to enforce a Candidate key cardinality (and provide an efficient look-up over such); where a Primary key can be viewed as a specialization of such.

(It must be a *unique* index to establish the cardinality; a non-unique index doesn't do.)

---

That being said .. SSN's *can* be duplicated (or even not assigned) and thus are not a great choice for a universal candidate key. For a person-based system - and *especially* for patients - I would use a *surrogate* key only (unless there is a guaranteed-stable like an Employee ID). Let the front-end find and resolve conflicts and provide a method of dealing with such duplicates cases (names, SSNs, etc) as they arise.

Also, depending upon the use-case, don't forget to allow for dealing with patients who's identity is not [yet] known ..

Comment: Okay. Thank you. One more thing...i have a primary key for one of my tables (not shown above) that has a PK consisting of 3 values, and when i tried to do two different insert commands, i got an error because the first two values were identical, even though the third was different. Why am i getting an error when the third value is different?

Comment: @jordpw The violation was probably caused by a different constraint left in. However it's hard to say more without the exact schema, data, and error message.